# Find rows in which id can be in one of several columns

Tags: mysql

Is there a more elegant SQL query for selecting rows in which ID can be in col1 or col2 or col3, etc. without a long condition containing plenty of OR operators ?

I'd like to produce the same result as the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab 
WHERE (col1 = _x_ OR col2 = _x_ OR col3 = _x_);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like :

```
 select * from tab where 'x' in (col1, col2, col3...)
```